# How to remove Envoy response header?

Tags: api-gateway, envoyproxy

Envoy proxy add some sensitive header, eg: Server, X-Envoy-Upstream-Service-Time...

I want to disable or remove those headers. How can I do that?

Thank for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Though there are some headers that can't be removed, I think all of these you show here can be stripped using the `request_headers_to_remove` field in the `RouteConfiguration`.

Check the [docs here](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/api-v2/api/v2/route.proto#routeconfiguration) for usage.

Comment: Can I use this configuration via Consul? I'm using Consul Ingress Gateway.

Comment: I'm not sure, I haven't used Consul connect, but you'd need to check their docs as to whether they support that bit of Envoy.